# Calling compounds electron deficient

Tags: electrons, ionic-compounds

I believe this is a conceptual question and might sound silly, but please help me with it:

I can understand when ions like $\text{Co}^{3+},\text{Mg}^{2+}$ are called electron deficient, because they have no valence electrons, but how do I call a compound like $\text{AlCl}_3$ electron deficient? What's the basis for calling such a compound electron deficient?

Comment: Is aluminium's octet complete?

Comment: Yeah, I believe aluminium's octet is complete.

Comment: @DhrubajyotiGhosh No, it's not. Count the valence electrons again.

Comment: Being electron-deficient would imply that the molecule possesses vacant MO which can feasibly accept electrons from an effective Lewis base. And yes, AlCl3 has an incomplete octect(6 electons).

Comment: An interesting question is whether $\ce{AlCl3}$ really exists under the given conditions. Perhaps we rather have $\ce{Al2Cl6}$. Then counting might be different.

Comment: @andselisk Sorry, so silly of me. Yeah, aluminium does have an incomplete octet...

Comment: @DhrubajyotiGhosh No, it's not silly, it's fine. Only the one who does nothing is never mistaken. You can post an answer to your question if you solved the issue yourself:)